# I am using CreateView in django but getting error- The view blog.views.PostCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

**I am having a post model with a user having OneToMany Relationship with inbuilt user model for authentication**

**my urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# from views import PostView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostView.as_view(), name='blogHome'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about')
]
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView, 
    CreateView
)
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')

class PostView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_published']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'body']

    #to add author before validation
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Post Model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**I am using post_form.html as the template name**

**post_form.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/layout.html' %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
<div class="content-section p-20">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group p-30">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create new post</legend>
      {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

**I am a beginner in Django , please tell if anything more is needed to solve the problem. Also why this type of error is coming only with Createview and not with other views**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the return of `super().form_valid(form)` is `None` and not a valid response. I don't know much of this design pattern in Django but seeing your other methods seems like this view is decorated by some method which returns a valid response. So you should not return something in your implementation. So, drop the `return` and test again.